# How i can make a "slider" from right to left (or whatever) by clicking on Nav arrow

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jQuery. I need to #reviews divs (`#rev1`, `#rev2`, `#rev3`) "slide" one by one when click on `#arrowr`. This code works but after click on `#Arrowr` @ `#Rev3` it doesnt Change to `#rev1`. Can you please point me the way to solve this. How i can make divs change one by one when i click the `#arrowr`? And create the Loop? PLease! Sorry for my poor english.

```
<div id="reviewsc">
    <div id="reviews">
        <div id="rev1" class="revv">rev1</div>
        <div id="rev2" class="rev">rev2</div>
        <div id="rev3" class="rev">rev3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="arrowr">></div>
</div>
<style>
    .rev {
        margin-left: -9999px or opacity:0 or display:none;
    }
    ;
    .revv {
        margin-left: 0px or opacity:1 or display:block;
    }
    ;
</style>
```

```js
$('div#arrowr').click(function () {
    $('#rev1').removeClass('revv').addClass('rev').next().removeClass('rev').addClass('revv');
    if ($('#rev2').hasClass('revv')) {
        $('div#arrowr').click(function () {
            $('#rev2').removeClass('revv').addClass('rev').next().removeClass('rev').addClass('revv');
        });
    }
    if ($('#rev3').hasClass('revv')) {
        $('div#arrowr').click(function () {
            $('#rev3').removeClass('revv').addClass('rev');
            $(this) // How i can go Back to my #REV1 Div? And start the cycle again
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you want to create a loop of slides you should check if your current slide is the first or the last one. If for example your current slide is the last one, you have to relocate the first slide after your last slide and then continue the loop upon click or an interval.

Comment: Share your css and make fiddle if you can (jsfiddle.net). I don't have code to work on actually. So even I can help, that will be only useless text without an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the others are hidden by default:

```
var ctr = 1;
var max = $('#reviews').children().length;

$('div#arrowr').click(function () {
    $('#rev'+ctr).removeClass('revv').addClass('rev');
    ctr++;
    if(ctr > max){ //ctr = max+1 => reset ctr
        ctr = 1;
    }    
     $('#rev'+ctr).removeClass('rev').addClass('revv');
});
```

for the other direction:

```
$('div#arrowl').click(function () {
    $('#rev'+ctr).removeClass('revv').addClass('rev');
    ctr--;
    if(ctr == 0){ //ctr = 0 => reset ctr
        ctr = max;
    }    
     $('#rev'+ctr).removeClass('rev').addClass('revv');
});
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phgXu/2/

Comment: Can you please point me to the Topic about "ctr" ? http://bit.ly/18p6htD (cant find it by myself)

Comment: ctr is just a variable....you know what a variable is, right? => http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: oh right. is this script Adds "1" to "#REV" and it becomes #rev1 or "#REV1+1" = #rev2, rev3 etc ?

Comment: yes. and max is the maximum of the elements. note that they NEED to be named `revX` with X being an ongoing number